# iOS when one views height increase with code , alignment is deteriorating

Tags: ios, view, height, vertical-alignment

I am trying raise the height of the ranked successive views. There is a certain distance between each of these views.(Vertical spaces)When I increase the height of one of them, distorted distance between the bottom. I can not align all elements under one single at a time. This event is automatically done on Android. How do I make this operation on iOS.

That is the problem

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using auto layout? What constraints do you have?

Comment: in iOS it is not handled automatically you need to use auto layouts to make UI elements adapt to the changes in the frames (size+origin) of the surrounding elements. Go through this tutorial series to get the idea of auto layouts.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

P.S: This tutorial is in Objective-C but you can find its updated Swift version too.